# Not able to figure out why Jfrog artifact is not being uploaded

Tags: gradle

I am having difficulties including this in my build.gradle. I tried to follow along with various tutorials, but I keep getting stuck. If anyone has any ideas, please let me know, I do not really know what I am doing as it is my first time with making a gradle project.

```
`buildscript {
    def user = System.getenv("USER")
    def pass = System.getenv("PASSWORD") 
    def url1  = System.getenv("CONTEXTURL")

    repositories {
        maven {
            url url1
            credentials {
                username = user
                password = pass
            }
        }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies { classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:4.28.1" }
}

plugins {
    // Apply the Java Gradle plugin development plugin to add support for developing Gradle plugins
    id 'java-gradle-plugin'

    // Apply the Groovy plugin to add support for Groovy
    id 'groovy'
}

group 'test'
version '1.2-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.artifactory'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url System.getenv("URL") }
}

ext {
    isSnapshot = version.endsWith("SNAPSHOT")
}


artifactory {
    def user = System.getenv("USER") 
    def pass = System.getenv("PASSWORD")
    def url  = System.getenv("CONTEXTURL")

    contextUrl = url
    publish {
        repository {
            repoKey = isSnapshot ? 'plugins-snapshot-local' : 'plugins-release-local'
            username = user
            password = pass
        }
        defaults {
            publications('maven')
        }
    }
}

publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // Use the awesome Spock testing and specification framework
    testImplementation libs.spock.core
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher'
}

gradlePlugin {
    // Define the plugin
    plugins {
        greeting {
            id = 'nested.set.domains.greeting'
            implementationClass = 'nested.set.domains.NestedSetDomainsPlugin'
        }
    }
}

// Add a source set for the functional test suite
sourceSets {
    functionalTest {
    }
}

configurations.functionalTestImplementation.extendsFrom(configurations.testImplementation)
configurations.functionalTestRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom(configurations.testRuntimeOnly)

// Add a task to run the functional tests
tasks.register('functionalTest', Test) {
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.functionalTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.functionalTest.runtimeClasspath
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

gradlePlugin.testSourceSets.add(sourceSets.functionalTest)

tasks.named('check') {
    // Run the functional tests as part of `check`
    dependsOn(tasks.functionalTest)
}

tasks.named('test') {
    // Use JUnit Jupiter for unit tests.
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
`
```

I get this when I run ./gradlew artifactoryPublish --stacktrace
`./gradlew artifactoryPublish --stacktrace

> Task :extractModuleInfo
> No publisher config found for project: test-project

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
`